# What is the simplest notation to refer to set of random variables sampled from a given distribution

Tags: notation

This is a question about notation convention. In statistics, to write that a random variable $X$ is drawn from a Poisson distribution with a rate $\lambda$, you might write

$$X \sim Poisson(\lambda)$$

Would there be a simple formulaic way to write: "a set of N numbers, $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^N$, where each is a random variable drawn from a Poisson distribution." Is it conventional to write something like $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^N \sim Poisson(\lambda)$ or $\{X_i \sim Poisson(\lambda)\}_{i=1}^N$?

In the above example, they would be drawn from a Poisson distribution with the same rates for each random variable. What if we have a set of $N$ rates, $\{\lambda_i\}_{i=1}^{N}$ and for each rate we want to drawn a single random variable with a Poisson distribution with that rate? $\{X_i \sim Poisson(\lambda_i)\}_{i=1}^N$? I guess I'm not very familiar with set notation so that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 2):

I would use $X_1, \ldots, X_n \sim \mathcal{P}(\lambda)$.

If in addition they are independent, I would say $X_1, \ldots, X_n \sim \mathcal{P}(\lambda)$ iid.